Issues with Custom Teams Apps Displaying SharePoint Pages in "New Teams"
I've created a couple of simple custom Teams apps designed primarily to display our tenants' SharePoint pages as tabs. For example, we have a Support App that includes several Support Site pages as tabs.
I implemented these apps easily using the Developer Portal, adding the SharePoint sites as static tabs within a personal scope. However, these tabs are not functioning correctly in the "New Teams". They do work if I open another app (created with Viva Connections that connects to a random SharePoint site) and then switch back to my original app. But once I close Teams completely and restart it, I have to repeat the process of opening a "working" app first to make the old custom apps display the SharePoint sites again.
I find it very confusing to understand what's happening. Did the old Teams manage authentication differently? I’ve found a lot of information online, but it doesn’t seem relevant to the simple app I want to create. I don’t need full-on SSO since the same setup worked with the old Teams.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!
Steps to Reproduce

Create a Custom App with "Developer Portal" in Teams
Create a tab feature with a couple of tabs that lead to some sharepoint sites
Preview the App -> You will not see loaded sites in the new Teams
First opening of the custom app
Start a working (preferably another custom app) that loads the sites
Now you are able to use your Custom App until you (for my testing) reinstall Teams or repair it.
Working Custom app after starting the other app

I have no idea what to do, because the app worked without any problems in the old teams.

It looks like this question is not about programming.

Since it is possible to work the apps with Teams Toolkit i believe it is, also think that i find here the answers im looking for. Its clearly not possible to make the app with the developer portal, there is the need for more work within the Teams Toolkit.

To resolve the issue with your custom Teams app not displaying SharePoint pages correctly in the "New Teams," you can modify the URL in your app manifest. Instead of linking directly to your SharePoint page, prepend the URL with the following:
https://MyTenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=https://MyTenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/MyPage.aspx
This should handle the authentication redirect and allow the SharePoint pages to load properly within your custom app.
has context menu

I think there's a way to hoist this signin process using a redirect within SharePoint specifically to handle coming from Teams. Instead of putting a link directly to your page in the App Manifest, e.g.
https://MyTenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/MyPage.aspx

Rather prepend it with the following:
https://MyTenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=https://MyTenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/MyPage.aspx

That should do what you need I think.
